# Passing $scope variable value to a factory variable/function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to pass the value of a $scope variable from my angular controller to my angular factory, where this value is further being used to do other calculations.

Controller :

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('MyController',['$scope', function($scope)
{
    $scope.selectedValue = function(value)
   {
      $scope.valueToSend = value + 1000;
   }
}]);
```

Factroy:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory("Factory", ["$q","$localStorage", function(q, $localStorage)
{
   var functionToGetValue = function()
   {
    return value;
   }
}
var x = { .... }
return x;
}]);
```

The 'value' in my controller is simply a radio button that is been selected.
Within my factory, the variable x has other functions that call my factory function `functionToGetValue`.

Is there some way I can pass $scope.valueToSend to my factory so that I can further use it there itself??

Comment: what is wrong with passing value to factory and then return its update to the controller?

Comment: I am not sure how to pass that value to the factory, and I want to avoid using $rootScope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a setter/getter method in your factory with which you can set the new value and when you want to reuse it , use the same method to get it as shown below :

```
angular.module('myApp').factory("Factory", ["$q","$localStorage", 

function(q, $localStorage)
{ 
   this.value = "";
   return {
    inputValue : function (value) {
       if(value)
         this.value = value;
       else
         return value;
    }   
  }
}
var x = { .... }
return x;
}]);
```

Now, from you controller,

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('MyController',['$scope', 'Factory'

function($scope, factory)
{
    $scope.selectedValue = function(value)
     {
      $scope.valueToSend = value + 1000;
       factory.inputValue($scope.valueToSend); // this will set the new value in the factory.
     }

console.log(factory.inputValue()) // this will get the value from the factory.

}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
angular.module('myApp').factory("Factory", ["$q","$localStorage", function(q, $localStorage)
{
   var value;
   var x = {
     setValue = function(val) {
         value = val;
     };
     functionToGetValue = function()
     {
        return value;
     }
   }
   return x;
}]);
```

Create factory like the above code and use that factory in your  controller. use `Factory.setValue(valueToPass)` and `Factory.functionToGetValue()` to get value passed value back.